# Subscribe inside useEffect doens't work in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, branch.io

I have the following code which I use to subscribe to branch.io. Here, the first console.log() is printed. But it doesn't go beyond that. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import branch from 'react-native-branch';

import {
  Button,
  InviteSummary,
  ListItem,
  ScreenContainer,
  Seperator,
  Label,
} from 'components';

import { APP_HOME_SCREEN } from 'common/constants/screens';
import { copyContent, shareContent } from 'library/Utils';

import ChevronRight from 'res/icons/Chevron/Right';
import Copied from 'res/icons/System/checked.svg';
import Copy from 'res/icons/System/Copy';

const SCREEN_TITLE = 'Invite and earn';
let _unsubscribeFromBranch = null;

const Invite = () => {
  const [referralLink, setReferralLink] = useState('');
  const [linkCopied, handleCopy] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('before subscribe');
    _unsubscribeFromBranch = branch.subscribe(({ error, params }) => {
      console.log('in subscribe');
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error from Branch: ', error);
        return;
      }

      console.log('Branch params: ', JSON.stringify(params));

      if (!params['+clicked_branch_link']) return;
    });
  }, []);

  const handleCopyLink = (text: string) => copyContent(text, () => handleCopy(true));

  const handleShareLink = () => shareContent(referralLink);

  return (
    <>
      <ScreenContainer
        title={SCREEN_TITLE}
        backScreen={APP_HOME_SCREEN}
        backScreenIcon={<ChevronRight />}>
        <View>
          <InviteSummary
            upperMainText='S$40.00'
            lowerMainText='earned'
            leftSubText='7 invites earned'
            rightSubText='3 pending'
          />

          <Label
            type={Label.Types.BODY_SMALL}
            label='when you invite a friend to  no matter how many friends! To make things sweeter, each friend you invite gets S$5 too.'
          />
          <Label
            type={Label.Types.BODY_SMALL}
            label='Referral credit will be awarded to you automatically once your friend activates their Visa debit card.'
          />

          <Seperator />

          <Label
            type={Label.Types.BODY_SMALL}
            label='SHARE Your unique invite link'
          />

          <ListItem
            title={referralLink}
            rightIcon={linkCopied ? <Copied /> : <Copy />}
            disabled={linkCopied}
            onPress={() => handleCopyLink(referralLink)}
          />
        </View>
      </ScreenContainer>

      <View>
        <Button
          type={Button.Types.PRIMARY}
          text='SHARE LINK'
          disabled={!linkCopied}
          onPress={handleShareLink}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

export default Invite;
```

Comment: Can you share code for `branch.subscribe`? Seems it isn't finishing to call the passed callback.

Comment: Updated the code for the component. @DrewReese

Comment: I can see you already have a ticket with us. Can you share this there as well? Meanwhile we'll check this with our internal team

Comment: @KartikShandilya I could resolve the issue. Thanks very much. The issue was, one of my collegues had already subscribed to branch when the app starts because we need branch to log events. Thanks again.